# Node.js https server closes sockets instantly on connection

Tags: node.js, https

My server is closing every socket **instantly** on 'connection' so the data is not coming through! The socket close event only prints false and the socket has no error. There is no firewall. How do I debug this?

```
    var port=64972;
    var G={};


    G.hardhttps=require(__dirname+'/node_modules/hardhttps');
    G.hardhttps.globalAgent.options.ca=require(__dirname+'/node_modules/ssl-root-cas').rootCas.join('');
    G.pem={
        key:require('fs').readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.site/privkey.pem','utf8')
    ,   cert:require('fs').readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.site/fullchain.pem','utf8')
    ,   ca:G.hardhttps.globalAgent.options.ca
        };


    var mn={};
    mn.server=G.hardhttps.createServer({key:G.pem.key,cert:G.pem.cert,ca:[G.pem.ca],requestCert:false},function(q,a){
        var d='';
        q.on('data',function(data){d+=data;});
        q.on('end',function(){
            console.log(d);
            a.writeHead(200);
            a.end('hello');
            });
        });
    mn.server.on('error',function(e){
        console.log(e);
        fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'servererror.txt',new Error(e).stack);
        });
    mn.server.on('clientError',function(e,s){
        fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'serverclienterror.txt',[s.remoteAddress,new Error(e).stack]);
        console.log(e);
        s.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
        });
    mn.server.on('connection',function(s,req){
        console.log(s.remoteAddress);
        s.on('error',function(e){console.log(e);});
        s.on('close',function(why){console.log('close',why);});
        });
    mn.server.listen(port,function(e,r){
        if(e){
            fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'serverlistenerror.txt',new Error(e).stack);
            }
        else{
            fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'serverlistening.txt',true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is how I'm posing:

```
 G.needle.post(
   'https://'+location+':'+port
  ,{something:123}
  ,{json:true,key:G.pem.key,cert:G.pem.cert,ca:[G.pem.ca]}
  ,function(e,r){ ...
```

Comment: If you post a **way more** readable example, explain what modules you use and tell more precisely which log statements get printed to console someone may help you. When I look at this it is just not nice to read at all and I immediatly skip the question and try to answer something else..  In the end, this is a free help center so take some time to write an attractive question ..

Comment: I also noticed that the `hardhttps` module had it's latest push on 2015 so maybe you should not use it anymore.,